# IP address problem on 2nd network card

Tags: networking, 14.04, ip

I have a network at home with multiple clients, both wired and wifi. All but one of the clients connect to the network with an IP address that is within the range that the router assigns to them. The client not connecting as expected is running 14.04 LTS and have two network cards. The onboard network card is only 100 MBps, so I would like to connect it to the periferal network card with 1000 MBps speed. Oddly enough, that wired connection gives me an IP address of 90.226... something and not 192.168... that the all the other clients get assigned (including the troublesome client, when on the onboard network card). I still get internet access on the client, but no access to the rest of the network. How could I get the network card to use a proper network IP address?

Thanks,
Tomas

Comment: Which network IPv4 settings exist for your two cards ? Maybe you should activate only the 1000Mbps one with DHCP ?

Comment: Where can I find these settings?

Comment: Use System settings/Network/ . You should have one line for each network card. Select the line, click "Options" and then the IPv4 tab. Here, you can enable DHCP or disable the card.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and enter the following:

```
user@system:~$ ifconfig
```

I would like to see what comes up. you can edit your question with the info. to copy the terminal text shown highlighting it and right click to copy it.

Comment: Now this is strange, after waking the computer from one nights hibernation, the inet addr has changed from 90.226... to 192.168... in ifconfig. I can now also see the computer and its name among the clients in my router. However, when I browse networks in the file manager, I can't see the other computers in my network.

Comment: can you add a share manually? try the "connect to a server" in the file viewer and add a share this way. you would enter something like "smb://computername/sharedfolder/"

Comment: Yes I can and after a reboot I can even see the rest of the network :-)!